Equilibrium Non-Existence in Moral Hazard with Bilateral Risk Neutrality
Suppose we have one agent and one principal. The agent picks effort level $e\in \{0,1\}$ which is not contractible. The agent is risk neutral with ex-post utility $w-ce$ where $c>0$ and $w$ is the wage paid by the principal. The agent has no outside option so must accept any contract offered by the principal. The principal is also risk neutral. The profit outcome $\pi$ is contractible and its distribution depends on the agent's effort choice. Suppose that the PDFs of profit are $f(\pi|e=1)=2\pi$ and $f(\pi|e=0)=1$ for $\pi \in [0,1]$ with both $0$ outside $[0,1]$. Finally, assume that the agent has limited liability: $w(\pi)\geq \underline{w}$ for all $\pi \in [0,1]$.
My question is, why does an optimal contract not necessarily exist in such a scenario? This question is a subpart of a past exam question.
To approach the problem, I take the Grossman-Hart approach of first solving the cost minimisation problem to implement $e=1$, $$\min_{w(\cdot)} \int_0^1 2\pi [\pi-w(\pi)]d\pi$$ $$st \ \begin{cases}
    w(\pi) \geq \underline{w}  & (LL)_{\pi} \ \forall \pi\in [0,1] \\
    \int_0^1 2\pi [w(\pi)-c]d\pi \geq \int_0^1 w(\pi)d\pi & (IC)
\end{cases}$$
I define the Lagrangian as $$\mathcal{L}=\int_0^12\pi[\pi-w(\pi)]-\lambda[2\pi c-(2\pi-1)w(\pi)]-\mu(\pi)[\underline{w}-w(\pi)]d\pi$$
From this, I have derived the following Borsch rule $$0\geq -2\pi +\lambda (2\pi -1)$$ with equality when $w(\pi)>\underline{w}$. From this, I conclude that there can only be at most one $w(\pi)$ which is above $\underline{w}$. As the profit distributions are absolutely continuous w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure, this cannot possibly incentivise the agent to take $e=1$, so a solution to the cost minimisation problem may not exist.
Therefore, if there exists some contract which incentivises $e=1$ and is more profitable than than the flat contract $w(\pi)=\underline{w}$ (incentivising $e=0$), then an optimal contract may fail to exist.
Can someone explain intuitively why an optimal contract may fail to exist in this situation? I think what is happening is that the principal really wants to make the agent the residual claimant to the profits but cannot due to limited liability. Instead, I think what the principal tries to do is set $w(1)=\infty$ and $w(\pi)=\underline{w}$ for all $\pi<1$. The point $\pi=1$ is where two distributions are most distinguishable. So, for any other contract which pays some wage above $\underline{w}$ for an outcome $\pi<1$, we could reallocate this wage payment to better reward $\pi=1$. This would 'loosen' the (IC) constraint as the $e=1$ distribution first-order stochastically dominates the $e=0$ distribution. This would then allow for a lower average (under the $e=1$ distribution) wage payment whilst still incentivising $e=1$. Therefore, I think there is some sort of "witches hat" phenomenon where there is always a profitable deviation to larger and larger wages concentrated closer to the point $\pi=1$.
Is this interpretation and method of showing an optimal contract may fail to exist correct?
